# Why are missing values being converted to character strings ("NA") using case_when in R?

Tags: r

I have an issue where missing values are converted to the actual character string "NA" after using `case_when` - can someone please advise me where my code is incorrect, and possibly suggest an alternative method that does not convert missing values to character strings?

Here is an example:

```
# make the tibble
df <- structure(list(animal = c("cat", "dog", "mouse", "rat", 
"pidgeon", "fish"), value = c(-2.71, -2.63, 
-2.66, -6.99, -2.11, -6.44), ID = c("2700", 
NA, NA, "4821", "55117", NA)), row.names = c(NA, -6L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

df
# A tibble: 6 x 3
  animal  value ID   
  <chr>   <dbl> <chr>
1 cat     -2.71 2700 
2 dog     -2.63 NA   
3 mouse   -2.66 NA   
4 rat     -6.99 4821 
5 pidgeon -2.11 55117
6 fish    -6.44 NA   

# check that it has two NA values
sum(is.na(df$ID))
# [1] 3


# create a separate tibble to merge it with
new_vals <- structure(list(animal = c("dog", "pidgeon"), ID_new = c("123456", "25255")), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))

new_vals
# A tibble: 2 x 2
  animal  ID_new
  <chr>   <chr> 
1 dog     123456
2 pidgeon 25255
```

Now I `left_join` the two tibbles, and make the `case_when` statement:

```
df_new <- left_join(
        df,
        new_vals,
        by = "animal"
    ) %>%
    mutate(
        ID = case_when(
            is.na(ID) ~ paste0(ID_new),
            TRUE ~ paste0(ID)
        )
    ) 

> df_new
# A tibble: 6 x 4
  animal  value ID     ID_new
  <chr>   <dbl> <chr>  <chr> 
1 cat     -2.71 2700   NA    
2 dog     -2.63 123456 123456
3 mouse   -2.66 NA     NA    
4 rat     -6.99 4821   NA    
5 pidgeon -2.11 55117  25255 
6 fish    -6.44 NA     NA 

sum(is.na(df_new$ID))
[1] 0
```

Although there are clearly NA values within df_new$ID, these are now no longer counted as actual missing values.  Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is that there is an unnecessary `paste0` in the expression

```
paste0(NA)
#[1] "NA"
```

It is documented in `?paste`

> Note that paste() coerces NA_character_, the character missing value, to "NA" which may seem undesirable, e.g., when pasting two character vectors, or very desirable,

If the intention is to convert to `character` class (although the input columns are `character` class)

```
as.character(NA)
#[1] NA
```

returns the correct type of NA i.e. `NA_character_`.  Compared to the behavior of `paste`, `stringr::str_c` returns the correct `NA` by default

```
str_c(NA)
#[1] NA

is.na(str_c(NA))
#[1] TRUE
```

---

As these are `character` columns and we are not doing any `type` conversion (if needed use `as.character` instead of `paste0`  as paste it for concatenating two strings or string columns together)

```
df_new <- left_join(
    df,
    new_vals,
    by = "animal"
) %>%
mutate(
    ID = case_when(
        is.na(ID) ~ ID_new,
        TRUE ~ ID
    )
)
```

-testing for NA

```
sum(is.na(df_new$ID))
#[1] 2
```